# Ordenar una tabla por atributo de otra tabla relacionada: cómo mejorar la velocidad

Tags: sqlite3

Tengo una tabla de agenda telefónica con 726.000 registros (sqlite).

El archivo sqlite está aquí: https://1drv.ms/u/s!Ar9mkZ1CPa2WhkUSJLxLI0WKV_TP

Éstas son las columnas:

```
Name    Declared Type   Type    Size    
nbmId   INTEGER INTEGER 
nbmCodigo   VARCHAR (6) VARCHAR 6   
abmNombre   VARCHAR (320)   VARCHAR 320 
abmNombrePlano  VARCHAR (320)   VARCHAR 320
nbmCiudad   INTEGER INTEGER 
nbmTelefono VARCHAR (9) VARCHAR 9
nbmCalle    INTEGER INTEGER
nbmNroPuerta    VARCHAR (5) VARCHAR
nbmLongitud VARCHAR (5) VARCHAR
nbmLatitud  VARCHAR (5) VARCHAR
```

Estoy utilizando c# WinForm DataGridView virtualmode.

Estoy utilizando esta sentencia para leer los datos:

```
SELECT bm_ppal.nbmId, bm_ppal.nbmCodigo, bm_ppal.abmNombre, bm_ppal.nbmCiudad, ciudad.a47Nombre, ciudad.n47Depart, depto.a46Nombre, 
bm_ppal.nbmTelefono, bm_ppal.nbmCalle, bm_calles.abmNombre, bm_ppal.nbmNroPuerta, bm_ppal.nbmLongitud, bm_ppal.nbmLatitud
 FROM bm_ppal 
 LEFT JOIN ciudad ON ciudad.n47Id = bm_ppal.nbmCiudad
 LEFT JOIN bm_calles ON bm_calles.nbmId = bm_ppal.nbmCalle
 LEFT JOIN depto ON depto.n46Id = ciudad.n47Depart
 ORDER BY bm_ppal.nbmId
 LIMIT 512
 OFFSET 0
```

Demora 157ms.

Pero si quiero cambiar el orden:

```
SELECT bm_ppal.nbmId, bm_ppal.nbmCodigo, bm_ppal.abmNombre, bm_ppal.nbmCiudad, ciudad.a47Nombre, ciudad.n47Depart, depto.a46Nombre, 
bm_ppal.nbmTelefono, bm_ppal.nbmCalle, bm_calles.abmNombre, bm_ppal.nbmNroPuerta, bm_ppal.nbmLongitud, bm_ppal.nbmLatitud
 FROM bm_ppal 
 LEFT JOIN ciudad ON ciudad.n47Id = bm_ppal.nbmCiudad
 LEFT JOIN bm_calles ON bm_calles.nbmId = bm_ppal.nbmCalle
 LEFT JOIN depto ON depto.n46Id = ciudad.n47Depart
 ORDER BY bm_calles.abmNombre
 LIMIT 512
 OFFSET 0
```

Demora 5699ms.

Hice otras pruebas y cuando trato de ordenar por un atributo perteneciente a las tablas relacionadas: ciudad, calles, depto resulta muy lento.

Creo que el problema es que los indices de las otras tablas, justamente están en las otras tablas.

Para crear el indice por nombre de la tabla calles utilizo esta sentencia:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idxbm_calles2 ON bm_calles(abmNombre);
```

Creo que la solución seria poder decirle que el indice lo guarde en la tabla principal pero tomando el dato de la tabla relacionada:

```
CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idxbm_ppal10 ON bm_ppal(calles(abmNombre));
```

Pero esta posibilidad no existe en sqlite (no sé si en otras DBMS).

¿Conocen alguna solución para este problema?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

El problema que estás teniendo no está relacionado con los índices, si no por la forma en la que se resuelve la consulta.

En el primer caso se obtienen los resultados de la tabla `bm_ppal` ordenados y por cada uno de ellos se resuelve el resto de uniones (`JOINS`) hasta satisfacer el límite impuesto de registros (512) y en cuanto se supera no se analiza ni se busca el resto de relaciones.

Sin embargo, en cuanto el orden está impuesto por una tabla que está unida, deben obtenerse todos los elementos que se desean ordenar (de la tabla `bm_calles` en tu caso, que es el penúltimo eslabón, por lo que deben desarrollarse las relaciones de las tres tablas antes de poder realizar la ordenación), por lo que por todos los elementos de `bm_ppal` se deben obtener las relaciones con `ciudad` y posteriormente con `bm_calles`, ahorrándonos tener que desarrollar únicamente las relaciones con `depto` en caso de alcanzar el límite, que no supone una mejora considerable.

Para optimizar tu consulta el registro por el que debe ordenarse debe encontrarse en la primera tabla, para evitar tener que desarrollar todas las relaciones para poder obtener los primeros 512 registros.

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT bm_ppal.nbmId, bm_ppal.nbmCodigo, bm_ppal.abmNombre, bm_ppal.nbmCiudad, ciudad.a47Nombre, ciudad.n47Depart, depto.a46Nombre, 
bm_ppal.nbmTelefono, bm_ppal.nbmCalle, bm_calles.abmNombre, bm_ppal.nbmNroPuerta, bm_ppal.nbmLongitud, bm_ppal.nbmLatitud
 FROM bm_calles
 LEFT JOIN bm_ppal ON bm_calles.nbmId = bm_ppal.nbmCalle
 LEFT JOIN ciudad ON ciudad.n47Id = bm_ppal.nbmCiudad
 LEFT JOIN depto ON depto.n46Id = ciudad.n47Depart
 ORDER BY bm_calles.abmNombre
 LIMIT 512
 OFFSET 0
```

Ahora la consulta vuelve a resolverse rápidamente sin tener que recorrer todos los elementos de las dos primeras tablas.

Edito: Acabo de hacer una medida de tiempo y en mis pruebas he conseguido reducir el tiempo de consulta de 2.4 segundos a 0.021 segundos.

Comment: No podría estar mejor explicado.

Comment: Gracias @FernandoForcén , quizá no sea la mejor explicación del mundo, pero lo intenté lo mejor que pude ;) Hay muchos SGBD que implementan un [optimizador de consultas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimizador_de_consultas) que realizan estas modificaciones automáticamente, pero obviamente sqlite parece no implementar dichas mejoras (o bien ésta en particular). Es normal si el objetivo de sqlite es ser un entorno liviano.

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia, en este caso la tabla bm_ppal apunta a calles y ciudad, y ciudad apunta a depto. Como sería el orden de los LEFT JOIN para consultar el nombre de la ciudad o el nombre del depto ?

Comment: Y si quiero los últimos registros donde el offset es 726000 ? Conoces algún proyecto de optimizador de consultas que pueda adaptar para sqlite ?

Comment: Date cuenta que en las relaciones da igual el lado de la relación, es la misma, la relación es bidireccional. Por eso se mantienen los mismos LEFT JOIN cambiando únicamente la tabla que hay que unir manteniendo la relación entre ellas. En cuanto a lo del offset no sé a qué te refieres, recuerda que existe un identificador único de registro en sqlite que podrías usar en algunas consultas o cláusulas `WHERE`. Lo de los optimizadores de consultas, quizá deberías usar un SGBD más potente que lo tenga implementado, como MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, etc...

Comment: Yo utilizo DataGridView - VirtualMode, entonces tengo un cache de 2 páginas de 512 registros cada una, mientras me muevo dentro de esos 1024 registros no se vuelven a producir lecturas,  el select que puse más arriba es el que se utiliza en los primeros 512 registros, pero si voy al final de la tabla el offset sería 724000 y el limit seguiría siendo 512, en este momento me esta dando problema el orden por depto.a46Nombre al final, pues me repite "artigas" y debería ser "treinta y tres"

Comment: Esta es la orden: SELECT bm_ppal.nbmId, bm_ppal.nbmCodigo, bm_ppal.abmNombre, bm_ppal.nbmCiudad, ciudad.a47Nombre, ciudad.n47Depart, depto.a46Nombre, 
bm_ppal.nbmTelefono, bm_ppal.nbmCalle, bm_calles.abmNombre, bm_ppal.nbmNroPuerta, bm_ppal.nbmLongitud, bm_ppal.nbmLatitud
 FROM depto
 LEFT JOIN bm_ppal ON depto.n46Id = ciudad.n47Depart
 LEFT JOIN ciudad ON ciudad.n47Id = bm_ppal.nbmCiudad
 LEFT JOIN bm_calles ON bm_calles.nbmId = bm_ppal.nbmCalle
 ORDER BY depto.a46Nombre
 LIMIT 512
 OFFSET 724000;

Comment: Lo siento, no sé qué es "DataGridView - VirtualMode", supongo que será un término que no está relacionado con `sqlite`. En cuanto al `offset`, las optimizaciones que he hecho antes están basadas en terminar cuanto antes el `LIMIT`, por lo que cualquier uso de `OFFSET` deja de estar optimizado ya que tiene que interpretar todas las relaciones para llegar al elemento del resultado `724000`. Tanto tu consulta inicial como la que he optimizado sufren de rendimiento porque no es posible "saltarse" los valores anteriores para calcular cuál ocupa la posición `724000`. Si quieres pasamos al chat.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56176/discussion-between-oscargarcia-and-hugo-marino).